# How can our party forcibly change the alignment of an NPC?

Tags: dnd-5e, npc, alignment

I can’t really explain why as it would require a deep, deep delve into our campaign’s lore, but our party needs to find the way to change the alignment of an NPC.

He’s a homebrew nephilim that was more or less born and bred for war and evil, and has always had the alignment of lawful evil.  Recently, he spent time in the Beastlands and his alignment changed to neutral evil.

Whatever we do, we would almost certainly have to do by force, as he is not going to change by choice. We’ve looked around, but have been having trouble with the “force” part.

**How can our party forcibly change this NPC's alignment?**

Comment: Welcome to the site! You have an interesting idea here, but idea generation doesn't fit our site's Q&A model. You will be better off discussing around RPG forums such ad the ones on this [curated list](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go). There may also be an answerable question here somewhere if you pull the attention away from the broad, largely opinion-based question and into a discussion of possible options available in the rules rather than just 'Any ideas'. Thanks for visiting and happy stacking!

Comment: Joseph, if you can earn a little more rep, we can kick around some idea generation  [in RPG.SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=rpg.stackexchange.com).